# How to plot a function with an exponential multiplied by a sine function?

Tags: matlab, plot, trigonometry, exponential

Hello I need help plotting the below equation in matlab.

```
v=10.0004+10.229*e^(-3*t)*sin(5.196*t-257.856)
```

here is what I have but I keep getting an error:

```
t=[0:0.1:2];
v=10.0004+10.229*exp(t)*sin(5.196*t+257.856);
plot(t,v)


Error using  * 
Incorrect dimensions for matrix multiplication. Check that the number of columns in the first matrix matches the
number of rows in the second matrix. To perform elementwise multiplication, use '.*'.

Error in example (line 2)
v=10.0004+10.229*exp(t)*sin(5.196*t+257.856);
```

Comment: replace `*` by `.*`

Answer (score 1):

Because t is a matrix, you cannot simply input it as you would a single variable. You have to access each value individually and calculate a corresponding v, then you store that value and move on. Rinse and repeat for each value.

This can be visualized with a *for* loop. Get the length of your time variable, which will determine how many values you need to calculate, then let the loop run for the corresponding number of elements. Make sure the loop counter is also used to index each element in v.

```html
t = 0:0.1:2 ;

%For each element (n) in t, create a corresponding one of v.
for n = 1:length(t)
 v(n) = 10.0004+10.229*exp(t(n))*sin(5.196*t(n)+257.856);
end

plot(t,v)
```

As we can interpret from the loop, there is a need to do ***element-wise*** (good keyword to remember) multiplication. In other languages, you might HAVE to use the loop method. Luckily in Matlab there is a dedicated operator for this '**.***'. Therefore in Matlab you could simply modify your code as follows:

```html
t=[0:0.1:2];
v=10.0004+10.229.*exp(t).*sin(5.196.*t+257.856);
plot(t,v)
```

Either method gives you the desired plot. The first I included to illustrate the underlying logic of what you're looking to do, and the second to simply it with Matlab's syntax. Hope this helps guide you in the future.

Best of luck out there.

Comment: This is a surprisingly verbose and thorough answer for what is a very simple question. You'll go far with explanations like that! +1